# Spatial index vs two coordinates indexes

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

I have a table with two columns: latitude and longitude. I want to get all objects inside a "rectangular" (well, rectangular in a lat/lon coordinate metric) bounding box: min-max latitude and min-max longitude. Basically that boils down to the following pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE lat < :maxlat AND lat > :minlat 
    AND lon < :maxlon AND lon > :minlon
```

What's the best solution for indexing my table? A two-column index? Two indexes on the two columns? A spatial index?

I would like to know if a spatial index is really needed in that case, as you need a special column, specific libraries, all that at the expense of database portability and simplicity.

Note: I'd like to keep this question database-agnostic, but for the sake of completeness I mention the fact that I'm working with PostGreSQL 8, w/o (for now) PostGIS.

Comment: can you guarantee that you'll only ever perform this type of spatial query? If you ever need even a simple addition like finding the real world (great circle) distance between two points all those spatial libraries will come in real handy... Also, consider what will happen if the bounding box crosses the +/- longitude e.g. 170,0 -170,10 (this is a valid bounding box in the Pacific). perhaps consider asking in http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, I can guarantee that I will perform only this type of spatial query. And I already have functions to compute the great-circle distance between two point (Haversine function). As for crossing the Pacific, it's out of the covered zone (but could be easily handled by a small test that switch minlon and maxlon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your version of PostgreSQL: 8.0, 8.1, etc? If you have a "high version", you could try include **lat** and **lon** column as a *unique column of point type*. Like this:

```
create table MyTable (
   ...
   lat  integer,
   lon  integer,
   coor point,
   ...
);

insert MyTable (..., lat, lon, coor, ...) values (..., lat1, lon1, '(lat1, lon1)', ...)
...
```

And create the indexes needed to test:

```
create index MyTable_lat on MyTable (lat);
create index MyTable_lon on MyTable (lon);
create index MyTable_coor on MyTable using gist (coor);
```

Now you can test what type of query is faster:

```
explain analyze
select * 
from MyTable 
where lat < :maxlat and lat > :minlat 
and lon < :maxlon and lon > :minlon
```

Or:

```
explain analyze
select * 
from MyTable 
where coor <@ box '((:minlat,:minlon),(:maxlat,:maxlon))'
```

I did the test on PostgreSQL 9 (with 20000 records) and the second option is more faster.

Comment: My version is 8.4.10. You say *faster*, how much? I'm willing to trade speed against simplicity and portability.

Comment: Hi @IOranger, how much is relative. In a table with 20000 records, when I extract 465 records using lat and lon: (cost=22.59..190.13 rows=266 width=28) (actual time=0.260..0.406 rows=465 loops=1) With coor: (cost=4.41..60.17 rows=20 width=28) (actual time=0.165..0.250 rows=465 loops=1). When I extract 8515 records using lat and lon: (cost=0.00..545.00 rows=8270 width=28) (actual time=0.732..5.331 rows=8515 loops=1). With coord: (cost=4.41..60.17 rows=20 width=28) (actual time=1.699..2.684 rows=8515 loops=1).